# Vue.js - How to 'grab' a scroll event from a vuetify v-dialog component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The javascript project I am working on is trying to incorporate a 'scroll-to-top' button that only renders after scrolling down (y-axis) 20px inside a Vuetify v-dialog component. We also have a v-card and v-treeview (has scrollable list of items) inside of the v-dialog. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually 'grab' the scroll event within that v-dialog component to trigger anything.

```
<v-dialog>
  <v-card>
    <v-treeview>  //scrollable list
    </v-treeview>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Any thoughts??

Here is a very similar Codepen of what I am trying to accomplish.
https://codepen.io/carlos-henreis/pen/vzXKBJ

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the link

Comment: @DavidGo thanks for catching that!

Comment: So, you've tried to place @scroll event on the dialog, right?

Comment: And did you add scrolable prop? https://vuetifyjs.com/components/dialogs#scrollable

Comment: I did try those. Honestly, because the v-treeview is inside a v-card, that is inside a v-dialog, I'm not even sure which component is the one that is actually scrolled. I've tried adding a scroll event, and the v-scroll directive, on all of them and I can't get any scroll event to even trigger anything. The codePen example works perfectly as a stand-alone component tossed into the root-level of any page view, because it can be triggered by the DOM window event, but I just can't access any 'scroll' event from inside a Vuetify component.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it  and I see your pain:) The answer is - you do need `scrollable` prop in order it to work, and you need to fin element that actually is scrolled. For me it's `v-card-text`. Check the example shorturl.at/mAOW3

Comment: I got here because I'm looking for a way to manage scroll listening inside a dialog to create a sticky element at a certain spot... I don't have an answer to that but if you want to find the element that contains the scrollbar, you can just right click on the scrollbar and 'inspect element' that will take you to the element that contains the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue as OP. None of the expected behavior for v-scroll or $vuetify.goTo() occurred within the dialog.

Ultimately, I implemented a vanilla javascript solution by utilizing

[element.scrollIntoView() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

on an added div within the dialog.

In template:

```
<v-dialog>
  <div id="thisElement">
    <v-card>
      <v-treeview>
         //scrollable list
         <v-btn @click="goToTop">Scroll Up</v-btn>
      </v-treeview>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</v-dialog>
```

In methods:

```
goToTop() {
    document.getElementByID("thisElement").scrollIntoView();
  },
```

Comment: They're asking for the event that triggers when the view is being scrolled. So that they can trigger behaviour when the scrolling started. Your answer doesn't show how that is being done, I believe.

Comment: True, I was unfortunately unable to identify the event in dialog because it didn't occur within the dialog and instead would only occur at the document level. It is likely due to the fact that the dialog is removed from the normal document flow.

Answer (score 0):

- add "scrollable" prop to "`<v-card>`"
- add `v-scroll.self="onScroll"` to  (or element that's
  scrolling) (per v-scroll documentation)
- add id to 
  (`id="requestform"`) (to select for scrolltop)
- add button to scroll to
  top (same as codepen above)
- add toTop method:

  ```
  toTop() {
    document.getElementById('requestform').scrollTop = 0
  },
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have smooth transition:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```